# MySql fulltext search with multiple containing/starts with/ends with words or partial matching words

Tags: mysql, search, full-text-search

every one.

I'm using MySQL database and facing problem with a full text search. I converted my table to MyISAM.

Here is my query..

```
$inputwords=" balu text ama som" (// input words by user in a single input box)
$result=SELECT * FROM my table Where MATCH (data, remark, purpose) AGAINST ('$inputwords' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

It gives all the rows with exact match of any inputwords.

1. My requirement is for "balu"- baluch, balusahi, hotbalu etc . Same for all other words like wild card.
2. Again I Required the only rows which contains all words partially alike above.

Any help ...please.

Answer (score 0):

To get the `LIKE` behavior in FullText `MATCH() AGAINST()`, you have to use `*` for AGAINST which is the equivalent of using `%` for LIKE. The idea is to have whole string like this :

```
$inputWords = "*balu* *text* *ama* *som*";
```

Here is the code :

```
$inputWords = "balu text ama som"; // input words by user in a single input box

// Create array of words by splitting with space char
$keywords = explode(" ", $inputWords);

$words = '';

foreach($keywords as $key => $value) {
    // concatenate all words following by space, and add * at start and end of the word
    $words .= '*'.$value.'*';

    // add space only if it is not the last word
    if($key < count($keywords) - 1)
        $words .= ' ';
}
```

And then you can have your:

```
$result=SELECT * FROM my table Where MATCH (data, remark, purpose) AGAINST ('$inputwords' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

that for word "balu" will match baluch, balusahi, hotbalu.

I don't know how it drops the performance, but it's still way faster than a `Like '%word%'` in my Servers.

Comment: the * works only as truncation operator, so it's a "starts with";
it can't do "ends with", so a match like against('*text') doesn't work

Comment: @lunadir correct. but with MyISAM, default FULL TEXT search that is in natural language mode won't match a word present in 50% or more of the Table Rows. Therefore, either pass to InnoDB engine or use FULL TEXT in BOOLEAN mode with this fallback.

Comment: yeah i didn't notice the MyISAM part